# Arithmetic on Ranges

Tags: range, julia

If I have a `UnitRange`, how can I add/shift/translate the values?

Say I have `1:3`

And I want `2:4`?

`1:3 + 1` gives me `1:4`, as does `1:3 .+ 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:` operator has [lower precedence](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity-1) than the arithmetic operators, so your two expressions are equivalent to `1:(3 + 1)` and `1:(3 .+ 1)`. Try this:

```
julia> 1 .+ (1:3)
2:4
```